# (Java) Text Adventure: Closing the game if input is entered

Tags: java

I am trying to modify my friend's simple Text Adventure in Java. I am trying to add  a ‘quit’ option to the menu, and modify the loop in the main() method so that it exits if the user enters this command.

But this code stops the game from the very beginning no matter what the input is:

```
while (playerLocation==10);
            System.out.println("You won the game");
            break;
```

And this produces an error:

```
while(scanner.equals("9")) {
            System.out.println("You have quit the game.");
            break;
        }
```

---

Full code below:

```
package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice 
{

private final int NO_EXIT   =   99999; // indicates that there is no exit in that direction

private int map[][]         =   {{NO_EXIT,1,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT},       //  1
                                {2,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT},        //  2
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,3,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT},        //  3
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,4,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT},                //  4
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,5},        //  5
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,6,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT},                //  6
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,7},        //  7
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,8,NO_EXIT},        //  8
                                {9,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT},        //  9
                                {NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT,NO_EXIT}}; //  10


private String description[] = {"(Stage 1) stranded in dead-looking forest. You are trying to find your way out of here. You then see a pathway heading east.",
                                "(Stage 2) now in a large abandoned military base. There is no other way around and you see another pathway heading north.",
                                "(Stage 3) now brought by the path you took here in an abandoned farmhouse. You now see a cave up ahead on the northwest",
                                "(Stage 4) now inside a cave. It has an entrance to the west.",
                                "(Stage 5) currently in the left wing of the cave. On the southwest there is an entrance leading somwhere.",
                                "(Stage 6) halfway through to your escape. You are in the bottom of the cave. \nThere is a small hole ahead on your northeast, but you can fit right through",
                                "(Stage 7) inside a section where there is a body of water. On your southwest direction, you see a ladder leading somewhere.",
                                "(Stage 8) inside a slightly dark hallway. You see a light ahead in the southeast direction.",
                                "(Stage 9) now outside the cave. You see a path heading north connecting towards an establishment.",
                                "(Stage 10) finally on your destination!"};


private String objectName[]     = {"An adult magazine", "A fully loaded .45 calibre gun", "A motherboard from the 90s", "A syringe", 
                                    "A skull", "A worn out pair of shoes", "A Matchbox", "A Wooden Plank", "Illegal Drugs", "A bottle of whiskey" };
private int objectLocation[]    = {0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 7, 6, 2, 1};
private int playerLocation      =  0;



// Prints out a description of the location the player is currently in, including a list of any objects at that location
private void describeLocation()
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You are " + description[playerLocation]);
    System.out.println("\n\t\tIn this area, you found: ");
    int numObjects = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<objectLocation.length; i++)
    {
        if (objectLocation[i]==playerLocation)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\t\t" + objectName[i]);
            numObjects++;
        }
    }
    if (numObjects==0)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\t\tNo Item(s)");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

// implements a simple text-driven menu
private int getMenuSelection(Scanner s)
{


    // display menu
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    System.out.println("1. Go North");
    System.out.println("2. Go East");
    System.out.println("3. Go West");
    System.out.println("4. Go South");
    System.out.println("5. Go North East");
    System.out.println("6. Go North West");
    System.out.println("7. Go South East");
    System.out.println("8. Go South West");
    System.out.println("9. Quit Game");
    System.out.print("Enter command (1-9): ");
    // get and return the user's selection
    return s.nextInt();
}






// try to move in the specified direction
private void move(int direction)
{
    int nextLocation = map[playerLocation][direction];

    if (nextLocation==NO_EXIT)
    {
        System.out.println("\nThere is no way there. Try again!");
    }

    else
    {
        playerLocation = nextLocation;
    }
}

public void startGame()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        describeLocation();
        int selection = getMenuSelection(scanner);
        move(selection-1);



        while (playerLocation==10);
            System.out.println("You won the game");
            break;


    } while (true);     
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    practice adv = new practice();
    adv.startGame();


    }
}
```

So basically what I need to know is how to put an inventory after those things are corrected.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of your many problems is this code snippet:

```
while (playerLocation==10); // < Semi colon here means loop forever if playerLocation==10
System.out.println("You won the game");
break; // This will always happen.
```

You probably wanted this instead:

```
playerLocation = scanner.nextInt();
if (playerLocation==10){
    System.out.println("You won the game");
    break; // this will break the outer loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the playerLocation can never be 10, your array size is only 9. You have to start counting from 0 not from 1. The first value in an array is 0.

`while (playerLocation == 9) {
    System.out.println("You won the game");
    break;
}`

The next one is, that your moving to the direction, not to the new position. If the player want to go east, you change the position to the location 2 in the array.

So think about it and work with a switch case. It could be like this.

```
// try to move in the specified direction
private void move(int direction) {

    int x = 0;//this should be the actual position of the player
    int y = 0;//this should be the actual position of the player

    switch (direction) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("up");
        y++;
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("down");
        y--;
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("left");
        x--;
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("right");
        x++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```